# Cannot access internal interface "IWindowServices"

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to create a WindowService class that helps to open up new windows in ViewModels. However I'm getting this error: Cannot access internal interface "IWindowServices"

```
using System.Windows;

class WindowService:IWindowService
{
    public void ShowWindow(object viewModel)
    {
        var win = new Window();
        win.Content = viewModel;
        win.Show();
    }
}
```

Please help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/IWindowService.cs

This interface not targeted special for MVVM.
You should create and implement custom interface in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out...

Instead of trying to access the interface under System.Windows, I can create one myself